# Chained channel operations in a single `select` case

Tags: go

I try to multiplex 2 channels, A and B. A is sending with 10 milliseconds delay and B is 1 second. I use select to wait for A and B, and send the result to a fan-in channel, and then receive value in main.

```
package main

import  (
"fmt"
"time"
)

func talk(msg string, wait_time int) <-chan string {
    ch := make(chan string)
    go func () {
        for i:=0;i<5;i++ {
            ch <- fmt.Sprintf("%s %d", msg, i)
            time.Sleep(time.Duration(wait_time)*time.Millisecond)
        }
    }()

    return ch
}

func fanIn(input1, input2 <-chan string) <-chan string {
    ch := make(chan string)
    go func () {
        for {
            select {
                case t :=<-input1:
                    ch <- t
                case t := <-input2:
                    ch <- t
            }
        }
    }()

    return ch
}
func main() {
    ch := fanIn(talk("A", 10), talk("B", 1000))

    for i:=0; i<10; i++ {
        fmt.Printf("%q\n", <-ch)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Done\n")

}
```

This will get the correct result as shown below

```
"A 0"
"B 0"
"A 1"
"A 2"
"A 3"
"A 4"
"B 1"
"B 2"
"B 3"
"B 4"
Done
```

My question is, when I change the case statement, I got weird output. it seems some value were dropped, and of course no more value is received in fan-in channel and deadlock happened.

```
select {
                case ch<- <-input1:
                case ch<- <-input2:
            }
```

Result is like this:

```
"B 0"
"A 1"
"B 2"
"A 3"
"A 4"
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!
```

Anyone has any idea of this situation?

Comment: Rule of thumb: Only _one_ send/receive per select case! (Your `case ch<- <-input` is two: One send and one receive).

Answer (score 8):

That happens because in select only one channel read or write is non blocking.

All other operations behave normally.

So in this piece of code

```
select {
                case ch<- <-input1:
                case ch<- <-input2:
            }
```

it receives a value from `input1` (blocking). It waits for a delay and receives `A 0`.

It tries to write it to `ch`, non blocking.

If the code in `main` was fast enough to reach

```
 fmt.Printf("%q\n", <-ch)
```

line then write to a channel succeeds.

Then `fanIn` `for` loop starts second iteration: it picks the second `case` this time (it's not deterministic). At this point it's likely that the second goroutine has written the `B 0` value.

But there is a chance that the `main` function loop has not consumed the value from the combined channel.

So the value is dropped.

This repeats multiple times, you lose few values and end up having no writers and a reader waiting for the remaining values forever.

This slightly modified copy of code demonstrates it: https://play.golang.org/p/lcM5OKx09Dj

Comment: To the OP: as usually, read [the spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Select_statements), which says: «For all the cases in the statement, the channel operands of receive operations and the channel and right-hand-side expressions of send statements are evaluated exactly once, in source order, upon entering the "select" statement. <...> Any side effects in that evaluation will occur irrespective of which (if any) communication operation is selected to proceed.»

Answer (score 2):

I will explain why your value in channel has been dropped.
Base on the fact in Golang document about execution of select statement:

> For all the cases in the statement, the channel operands of receive operations and the channel and right-hand-side expressions of send statements are evaluated exactly once, in source order, upon entering the "select" statement. The result is a set of channels to receive from or send to, and the corresponding values to send. Any side effects in that evaluation will occur irrespective of which (if any) communication operation is selected to proceed. Expressions on the left-hand side of a RecvStmt with a short variable declaration or assignment are not yet evaluated.

The result is a set of channels to receive from or send to, because of this, when you pass channel in left-hand side, select statement first try to get **ALL** right-hand side statements are evaluated before trying to send to channel in left-hand side statement

Obviously, input1 and input2 must be received at one round of select statement, and then send to ch, so the ch channel **Always** has exact 5 value which mixed from intput1 and input2 **Equally** despite of their delay

You can see all data has printed when sending value to input1 and input2 channel in this code:
[Link](https://play.golang.org/p/NeUuW7d69eV)

Answer (score 1):

(my reading of this, I haven't seen a specific explanation of this particular combination of 'case' clauses in the GO docs).

When you have a 'select' that has 'case' clauses referring to multiple channels, GO will pick **any** of them that is available and take that as 'the channel that woke up the select'.

In your first code snippet, the 'case' clauses refer only to input1 and input2 (correct - what you actually wanted, i.e., "wait for either input1 or input2").

In the second snippet, you have all three (`input1`, `input2` and `ch`) in 'case' clauses, so the statement says "wait for `input1` or `input2` to be readable OR for `ch` to be writable". Now, `ch` can become writable easily due to main waiting on it, so your 'select' can wake up on that and end up executing a read on input1 or intput2 without those being readable at the moment (NOT what you wanted).